# Relative RecyclerView Scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview, android-recyclerview

I have an image and some text and below that i have a sliding tab layout with a view pager and the view pager has 3 fragments each having one recycler view each . Now my problem is that i want to scroll the recyclerview and at the same time i want to scroll the rest of the elements too. For eg when i scroll the recycler view i want  all other views to scroll as well. This my XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true"
>
 <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:src="@drawable/aal"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#98000000"
    android:id="@+id/innerColor"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/include"
        android:padding="13dp"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_bg"
            android:onClick="BackPressed"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            android:id="@+id/addAction"
            android:onClick="showImage"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_bg"
            android:tint="@color/icons"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sample "
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:id="@+id/textHeader"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_above="@+id/descText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/descText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:text="Sampletext"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Fbutton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Follow"
        android:onClick="followUnfollow"
        android:background="@drawable/follow_button_bg"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:textColor="#403e3e"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/Fbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

          <RelativeLayout
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/Fbutton"
              android:layout_marginTop="-80dp"
              android:id="@+id/relativeLayout5"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


              <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relStatMem"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/relativeLayout5">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/numImages"
                android:text="500"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/texts"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="PHOTOS"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/numImages"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relStatFol"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relStatMem"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/relStatMem">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/numMembers"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textsMembers"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="MEMBERS"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/numMembers"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
              <RelativeLayout
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/relStatFols"
                  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relStatFol"
                  android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/relStatFol">
                  <TextView
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/numFolls"
                      android:text="1B"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff"
                      android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                      android:textStyle="bold" />
                  <TextView
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/textsFol"
                      android:textSize="12dp"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff"
                      android:text="FOLLOWERS"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/numFolls"
                      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


              </RelativeLayout>
          </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
<!--In addition to the two java files we got from google git , this is what you need for tabs-->
<com.example.skmishra.plates.Library.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_below="@+id/innerColor"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!--For elevation add here-->


</com.example.skmishra.plates.Library.SlidingTabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tabs"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:fillViewport="false">
  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
  </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Google + Does that , i would like to implement something simillar
[image: When we scroll the posts upper profile layout also scrolls]

Answer (score 0):

I believe Google used a [Collapsing Toolbar Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html), which will collaps the toolbar on scroll or other events. 
You can find more information [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```